# Facebook finds thumbnail but doesn't use it in snippet

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

When checking some of our articles on the FB Debugger, it correctly gets the image to use, along with all other tags but does not put the image in the snippet.

Eg; on the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) put this url in;http://www.nova969.com.au/entertainment/katy-perry-getting-slammed-her-latest-costume

It shows the following;

[image]

It does this on all our links. It shows two warnings but no errors in the debugger.

We've had a few code changes lately, but nothing intentional has been done to this. Its been working well for months. (I say intentional because I'm reluctant to say "nothing has changed" because something has obviously changed, its just not something we did on purpose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has verified this issue as a bug, and claim to be working on it actively: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/